# pagefile and disk space monitoring on server 2012

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012, disk-space-utilization, pagefile

I have had a server crash recently because of the disk space.

Here is what I have:
a Hyper-V 2012 server with 1 win 2012 image
physical disk is 500GB server uses 800GB

It was OK for half a year but recently users started to upload all sort of data and 3 of my local drive got nearly 90% full. It this time the page file got bigger and the server went pause:critical disk space mode

I have now started to monitor the disk space on the hyper-v, image disks and the pagefile through powershell.

Would someone give some explanation what do I need to check from these csv log files?

I know this is weak explanation but I am a newbie and I am learning what to do. My aim is to prevent another crash by monitoring the usage and when it gets 90% of the usage I would alert users to act. This is a temporary solution for school time and I will 'reformat' or buy new disks to be able to cope with the load. However I would like to know how much I need to buy and what is the dynamic of usage of the school.

Please feel free to ask specific questions and I will dig out to make the question more precise. I also keen to learn to monitor page file usage which is auto setup by the server at this point.

Any hint or direction would greatly appreciate. (I inherited this server so I need to know what information to gather to get the full picture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but I would configure some monitoring platform like Nagios to watch the servers. Stuff like this happens all the time, and if this is a client, you need to know there's an issue before the users do. I have used Nagios for years to watch my servers, and it sends emails if there's anything that goes sideways. I have configured it to watch the local disk storage as well. You could look into other similar solutions.

Another way to do this would be to script your powershell check as a scheduled task that will send an email using sendmail if there's an issue with space. Really, anything you do going forward will be a time investment into learning. I honestly think you should learn something like Nagios, but learning some PS Scripts that also generate email alerts would be good as well.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I did run a regular Powershell script at the end. Monitored all the free space on the disks and checked the virtual space against the physical. Good or bad I don't know I survived and reformatted the disk at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step I would adjust all the clients so the page file is a fixed size, then you don't have to worry about it growing out of control:

You can use GPO to deploy this fix to many machines as described [in this post](http://tompopov.blogspot.com/2011/02/change-virtual-memory-using-group.html).

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kyle, what is the relation to the users PC to the server? sorry I am newbie on this topic as well. Thanks in advance